# run part of a script in IPython

Tags: ipython

I'd like to run part of a scritp (script.py) in IPython, up to line 90.
I have tried

```
%run -d -b90 script.py
```

as well as

```
%run -d -b 90 script.py
```

but I got the following message

> I failed to find a valid line to set a breakpoint
>
> after trying up to line: 100.
>
> Please set a valid breakpoint manually with the -b option

How can I do this in the IPython console? there is always the possibility to use an external command and copy the lines I am interested in to another file and run that new script.

thanks

Comment: What is the code at line 90 (give or take a line or two)?  Based on the error message I'm guessing it is a blank line.

Comment: Not a blank line, but a comment. If I set the breakpoint to a line of code, I get a syntax error reported for a line past the breakpoint.

Comment: If the file contains any syntax errors then it will break on the load stage, before any code is executed, so you cannot use part of a file that contains syntax errors - you will see the same thing when running in an IDE. You cannot set a breakpoint to a comment as there is no execution step to break on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed the line in question and it now works.